# Memcpy EXC_BAD_ACCESS code in iOS C library

Tags: c, exception, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I am using a library in C for iOS which crashes randomly once in a while. Its a memcpy call that fails and Im thinking this must be possible to prevent. I tried try-catch but did obviously not work on memcpy. Im not too familiar with C, so do you have any idea how I can avoid this crash. Currently the whole app is crashing randomly because of this library.

```
int cachecontroltoi(u8* s, u32 l){
    u32 ret = -1;
    u32 p;

    char buf[1024];
    int buflen=1024;

    if(l >= buflen){
       return ret;
    }
    memcpy(&buf, s, l); // <<-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Are there some obvious mistakes in this code or can the error be catched/oppressed somehow?

These are the variable values in the debugger when memcpy crashes[image]

Comment: Do you have a really small stack? The array is kind of large.

Comment: @KerrekSB I dont think thats the case. The error also seems to be when the s and l variables are small/empty.

Comment: Please show what is `s` pointing at.

Comment: you should remove the `&` in the memcpy line. `buf` is already the address of the array. How do you call this function and how do you declare this array?

Comment: @mch It's not the OP's [code](https://github.com/fkuehne/upnpx/blob/master/src/ssdp/ssdptools.cpp).

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok i see, this i probably an error originating somewhere else. s i usually something like this "(unsigned char *) s = 0x00000001039b2f6b" but at crash it is like this: "(unsigned char *) s = 0x0000000000000007". Is it possible to check for allowed address space?

Comment: @Zeezer Not reliably no,  Don't call this method with an invalid `s` parameter.